# SQL database PHP VLOOKUP equivalent?

Tags: php, html, sql, excel, vlookup

I want the data from my static SQL database (say database 1) to be pulled into database 2 when there is an update in database 2, i.e. after a new input.

Ultimately, a simple VLOOKUP of 'ID' in database 2, pulling 'DETAILS' from database 1, and showing the result in 'DETAILS' column in database 2, automatically when ID's come into database 2.

DATABASE 1

| ID | CAR | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22MAY | MERC | SPOILER |
| 23MAY | BMW | V12 |
| 24MAY | AUDI | HYBRID |

DATABASE 2

| ID | CAR | DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22MAY | MERC | ? |
| 23MAY | BMW | ? |
| 24MAY | AUDI | ? |

Know this is really easy on excel / VBA.

If anyone know how to replicate the below excel equivalent in php/sql:

=VLOOKUP('DATABASE2ID','DATABASE1',3,0)

SUMMARY : AUTO UPDATE 'DETAILS' IN DATABASE 2,AFTER EVERY TIME A NEW ID IS INPUT IN DATABASE 2

NOTES : Database, PHPMyAdmin SQL

Comment: You may read about after insert/update triggers in SQL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. Aware of this, the part I'm focused on is the conditional / dynamic aspect of that. i.e. AFTER ID inserted, find ID DETAILS in database 1, and display in column 3. Is there an easy way to do this, I suspect so